# How to randomly access nth element in StringTokenizer

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer, split

Is there anyway we can directly access a certain(lets say 20th) element in a stringTokenizer. Every now and then I need only a certain element from it and do not need others, yet I have to traverse through all elements.

**EDIT**: I also want to ignore empty elements.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try Apache Commons Lang's [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) class, which can split a string while ignoring empty elements and handling `null` strings for you.

A tokenizer would have to read at least n tokens in order to determine which is the n-th one. Thus it might be easier to just create a string array using `String#split()` or `StringUtils.split(...)`.

Note that I'd prefer `StringUtils.split(...)` since it doesn't return empty elements if I don't want them, i.e. `StringUtils.split(",a,b,c;;d,e,,f",";,");` would return `["a","b","c","d","e","f"]` whereas `String#split()` would return `["","a","b","c","","d","e","","f"]`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`String.split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for that instead of a `Tokenizer`.

For example:

```
String[] split = "you string is splitting".split(" ");
split[2];  // random access to the 3rd element of split
```

Of course, you will need to check that your `split` actually has that many elements before accessing its subindex.

Comment: Can it split at multiple, different delimiters?

Comment: Can it ignore empty elements?

Comment: Yes, you can split at **any** regular expression you want. That will give you a lot of flexibility.

Comment: @SyedAqeel basically yes, you could, for example, split on `,` or `;` meaning `"a,b;c"` would result in `["a","b","c"]`.

Comment: [http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)] - link to split

Comment: What about ignoring empty elements?

Answer (score 0):

Tokenizer is meant to access elements sequentially (kinda like a `LinkedList`). You have to go through all the tokens and store them in some kind of random-access collection (`ArrayList`), or use another method to split your original string / stream.